# Flink Kafka Producer for AVRO messages throwing UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: apache-flink, avro

I have flink pipeline defined as

1. consuming colon separated string from kafka topic
2. transforme it as AVRO record using map API
3. Producing it back to different kafka topic

The code is as below

```
DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("topic-input", new SimpleStringSchema(), prop));
SingleOutputStreamOperator<GenericRecord> transformedData = messageStream.map(new RichMapFunction<String, GenericRecord>() {
...
});             
transformedData.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer<GenericRecord>("topic-output", new KafkaSerializationSchema<GenericRecord>() {
            @Override
            public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(GenericRecord genericRecord, @Nullable Long aLong) {
                ...
                return new ProducerRecord(...);
            }
        }, prop, FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE));
```

I was getting below error, when produce the message to topic (topic-input), any clue?

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:116) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:78) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:224) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:217) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:208) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    ...
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Serialization trace:
reserved (org.apache.avro.Schema$Field)
fieldMap (org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema)
schema (org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528) ~[flink-dist_2.11-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    .....
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:46) ~[flink-streaming-java_2.12-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.CopyingChainingOutput.collect(CopyingChainingOutput.java:26)
```